# update value based on row number?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

i'm pretty new to SQL and stored procedures and i'm a bit stuck - so any help would be appreciated

how do i loop through each row and assign it the random value i'm generating?

Here is my Storedproc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StoredProc8
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @total INT 
DECLARE @Count INT = 0
DECLARE @Random INT = 0
SELECT @total = COUNT(CustomerID) FROM Customers
WHILE(@Count<= @total)
BEGIN


SELECT @Random = 2 * RAND()
EXEC ('update Customers set col1= ' + @Random )
SELECT @Count = @Count+1
END
END
```

Comment: Basically you need to assign 0 or 1 randomly and row number doesn't really matter?

Comment: use simple update Customers set col1=RAND();

Comment: @IlyaBursov won't work - number will be the same

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yea, i need to assign 1 or 0, row number doesn't really matter.. it's just that the next random number generated needs to be assigned to the next row. Right now all the rows are assigned the last random number generated =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simple need to assign 0 or 1 randomly - you can use RAND() with random seed:

```
UPDATE Customers SET COL1 = RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*2
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31699/9

Comment: hmm wont this give all the rows the same random number..? i need the rows to carry the new random number generated each time through the loop, rather than assigning all the rows to the same random number

Comment: No. NEWID() is guaranteed to be unique, and RAND() based on this seed will also be random. Give it a try. And you do not need the loop. One update should cover entire table. Just take a look at the demo in SQLFiddle

Comment: hmm how do i add this into the stored procedure though? when i set SELECT @Random =  RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*2 then it returns the same number for all the rows... and i can't seem to do EXEC ('update Customers set promotion = ' + RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*2) .. any ideas?

Comment: No. that `UPDATE` command should be *the only* command in your stored procedure. You don't need any other variables, you don't need a separate `EXEC`statement. So, technically, you don't even a stored procedure, just that single `UPDATE` statement from the answer

Comment: OH ok, removed loop and exec statement and everything.. and now it works, thanks man!

Comment: No problem :) Glad it worked for you. Just remember SQL is a set-based language a single command can affect multiple records.